# Batch if statement error

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to make a minesweeper in batch but i am having strange errors. When I run the file it lays 5 mines. Then it goes through the rest of the squares and checks to see how many mines are adjacent to each square. My problem is that it only senses an out put to the south-east. The south-east code is no different than the code for any other directions. This is very confusing to me. It seems like no one else has had this error. This is what an example output would be:

```
M 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 M 0
M 0 M 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 M 0
```

An answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
title Batch Minesweeper 
color 80 
set setX=1
set setY=1
set testX=1
set testY=1
set plrX=1
set plyY=1
set mines=0
set mineNum=0
set N=
set NE=
set E=
set SE=
set S=
set SW=
set W=
set NW=
set rect1_1= 
set rect2_1= 
set rect3_1= 
set rect4_1= 
set rect5_1= 
set rect1_2= 
set rect2_2= 
set rect3_2= 
set rect4_2= 
set rect5_2= 
set rect1_3= 
set rect2_3= 
set rect3_3= 
set rect4_3= 
set rect5_3= 
set rect1_4= 
set rect2_4= 
set rect3_4= 
set rect4_4= 
set rect5_4= 
set rect1_5= 
set rect2_5= 
set rect3_5= 
set rect4_5= 
set rect5_5= 
set mine1_1=0
set mine2_1=0
set mine3_1=0
set mine4_1=0
set mine5_1=0
set mine1_2=0
set mine2_2=0
set mine3_2=0
set mine4_2=0
set mine5_2=0
set mine1_3=0
set mine2_3=0
set mine3_3=0
set mine4_3=0
set mine5_3=0
set mine1_4=0
set mine2_4=0
set mine3_4=0
set mine4_4=0
set mine5_4=0
set mine1_5=0
set mine2_5=0
set mine3_5=0
set mine4_5=0
set mine5_5=0
cls
echo Batch Minesweeper
echo.
echo [1] - Play
echo [2] - Info
echo [3] - Exit
echo.
echo Batch Minesweeper made by Matt Pauly
choice /c 123 /n /m ""
if %errorlevel%==1 goto startGame 
if %errorlevel%==1 goto info 
if %errorlevel%==1 goto end

:startGame
cls
set /a ranX=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1
set /a ranY=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1
if not %mines%==5 (
    if !mine%ranX%_%ranY%!==0 (
        set mine%ranX%_%ranY%=M
        set /a mines=%mines% + 1
        goto startGame
        )
    goto startGame
    )
goto setup

:setup
cls
echo Loading...
set curVal=%setX%_%setY%
if %curVal%==1_6 goto display
if %setX%==6 (
    set setX=1
    set /a setY=%setY% + 1
    goto setup
    )
if !mine%setX%_%setY%!==M (
    set /a setX=%setX% + 1
    goto setup
    )
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set testX=%setX%    
set N=!mine%testX%_%testY%! 
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1 
set NE=!mine%testX%_%testY%!    
set testY=%setY% 
set /a testX=%setX% + 1 
set E=!mine%testX%_%testY%! 
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1 
set SE=!mine%testX%_%testY%!    
set testY=%setY%
set /a testX=%setX% - 1 
set S=!mine%testX%_%testY%! 
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% - 1 
set SW=!mine%testX%_%testY%!    
set /a testY=%setY% + 1
set testX=%setX%    
set W=!mine%testX%_%testY%! 
set /a testY=%setY% - 1
set /a testX=%setX% + 1 
set NW=!mine%testX%_%testY%!
set mineNum=0
if defined N if "%N%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined NW if "%NW%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined W if "%W%"=="M" set/a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined SW if "%S%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined S if "%S%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined SE if "%SE%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined E if "%E%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
if defined NE if "%NE%"=="M" set /a mineNum=%mineNum% + 1
set mine%setX%_%setY%=%mineNum%
set /a setX=%setX% + 1
goto setup

:display    
cls
::echo 5    %rect1_5%    %rect2_5%    %rect3_5%    %rect4_5%    %rect5_5%
::echo.
::echo 4    %rect1_4%    %rect2_4%    %rect3_4%    %rect4_4%    %rect5_4%
::echo.
::echo 3    %rect1_3%    %rect2_3%    %rect3_3%    %rect4_3%    %rect5_3%
::echo.
::echo 2    %rect1_2%    %rect2_2%    %rect3_2%    %rect4_2%    %rect5_2%
::echo.
::echo 1    %rect1_1%    %rect2_1%    %rect3_1%    %rect4_1%    %rect5_1%
::echo.
::echo      a    b    c    d    e 
echo 5    %mine1_5%    %mine2_5%    %mine3_5%    %mine4_5%    %mine5_5%
echo.
echo 4    %mine1_4%    %mine2_4%    %mine3_4%    %mine4_4%    %mine5_4%
echo.
echo 3    %mine1_3%    %mine2_3%    %mine3_3%    %mine4_3%    %mine5_3%
echo.
echo 2    %mine1_2%    %mine2_2%    %mine3_2%    %mine4_2%    %mine5_2%
echo.
echo 1    %mine1_1%    %mine2_1%    %mine3_1%    %mine4_1%    %mine5_1%
echo.
echo      a    b    c    d    e 
pause

:info

:end
exit
```

Comment: Maybe you want to learn about the `for` command, starting with `FOR /L %x in (1, 1, 5) DO echo %x`. Next try `FOR /L %x in (1, 1, 5) DO for /L %y in (1, 1, 5) DO echo %x_%y`. Finally replace `echo %x_%y` by `set mine%x_%y=0` to initialize your mine field to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your major problem is trailing spaces on lines. In a conventional `set` statement, any trailing spaces are included in the value assigned, and `"M"` and `"M  "` are completely different things, so if you have `set X=!something!` then the value assigned is different from that assigned by `set X=!something!`.

You also have a problem where you are confusing your `X` with your `Y`. For instance, setting `W` is done with `X` and `Y+1` - the same as setting `N`. This should be `X-1` and `Y`.

Comment: Load it into a text editor that has an option to remove trailing whitespace, so you can save it out without the trailing spaces.

Comment: I removed the trailing spaces but it is still not completely working. The X and Y are messed up but i have no idea why.

Comment: Still have your Xs and Ys confused. The calculation for `N` is the same as for `E` for instance; `SE` is in fact NW, `S` is E. and `if defined SW if "%S%"=="..` should probably be `if defined SW if "%SW%"=="...` Fix them all up (remember - North is Y+1, South Y-1, East X+1 and West - well, um - now what would that be?) and it all works!

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it figured out.